# is there any way to get the email if while login with Oauth (Google,Github)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

[image]

I have attached my login screenshot ,please check and let me know if there is any way to get email id in DB[image]

Comment: If you want to get the email, you will have to add this in your scope when getting the token. For google, your scope would be something along the lines of 'openid email'. Github and Facebook may use different values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write separate code to get the text typed into the input

Comment: i have tried with server side i couldn't able to get

Comment: Firstly you need to write client side code to capture the email address from the input, then secondly you need to write code to send the captured email address to an endpoint on the server. Once it's been sent to the server endpoint you can do as you wish with it. If you want to tip me in crypto I can write the code or a sample for you.